# python lists with for loop and if-else statement

Tags: python, list, for-loop, if-statement, conditional-statements

I want to use the one lined syntax for the "for_loop/if/elif/else/lists" for the code under:

```
for i in range(20):
    if(i<15):
        print("True")
    else:
        print("False")
```

this is a part of it

```
[True for i in range(20) if i<15]
```

How to add the "else" for it?

Comment: The `[x for x in z     if x]` is for filtering ,  `[x if x else y      for x in z]` is for mapping each value regarding a condition

Comment: try this : `[True if i<15 else False for i in range(20) ]`

Answer (score 1):

Try it.

```
s = [True if i<15 else False for i in range(20)]
print(s)
```

output

```
[True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, False, False, False, False, False]
```